# Is there a way to skip YouTube's "Before you continue to YouTube" cookies message on new browsers via the URL itself?

Tags: html, web, url, browser, youtube

If you open a link to a YouTube video or channel on a fresh browser you'll get this pop up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU8lT.png

Is there something you can add to the end (or middle!) of that URL that will automatically skip that page?

Use case: I'm automatically displaying a user supplied YouTube like in the built in Unreal 4 web browser and it breaks because this screen now comes up.

Answer (score 5):

Either when selecting `REJECT ALL` or `ACCEPT ALL` YouTube sets a [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) called `SOCS` to the value `CAESEwgDEgk0ODE3Nzk3MjQaAmVuIAEaBgiA_LyaBg` that is encoded in base64. As far as I know the only way to get rid of the consent screen is to pass this cookie when requesting the webpage.

You can verify my answer by running:

```bash
curl 'https://www.youtube.com' -H 'Accept-Language: en' | grep 'We use' | wc -l
```

Note that `We use` is the start of `We use cookies and data to` of the consent screen.

You'll  get `1` which means that the consent screen is present with such a simple request.

While with:

```bash
curl 'https://www.youtube.com' -H 'Accept-Language: en' -H 'Cookie: SOCS=CAESEwgDEgk0ODE3Nzk3MjQaAmVuIAEaBgiA_LyaBg' | grep 'We use' | wc -l
```

You'll get `0` which means that the consent screen is absent.

Comment: The cookie doesn't always have that value, mine is similar but a few of the characters are different. It's also different depending on whether you select "reject" (starts with CAESE) or "accept" (starts with CAISE). Google says this cookie "lasts for 13 months and is also [along with CONSENT] used to store a user’s state regarding their cookies choices." https://policies.google.com/technologies/cookies

Comment: Note that the `SOCS` value provided in this answer is for the `REJECT ALL` option. This option prevents the client from accessing some personalized content, including the auto-generated mix playlists. Therefore, you might need to use the value corresponding to the `ACCEPT ALL` option instead, which is `CAISNQgDEitib3FfaWRlbnRpdHlmcm9udGVuZHVpc2VydmVyXzIwMjMwODI5LjA3X3AxGgJlbiACGgYIgLC_pwY`.

Comment: This answer just saved my life getting foo_youtube Foobar2000 component to play Youtube audio. Pasted the cookie value in Preferences|Youtube|Network|Storage|Modify|SOCS cookie value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the surrounding YouTube interface, and just want to show the video, you can display the "embedded" version. Replace the `watch?v=` in the URL with `embed/`.

Here's some javascript, as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){window.location%20=%20window.location.toString().replace('watch?v=',%20'embed/').replace(/&[\s\S]*/,%20'');})()
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! If the link ends up being a channel link, do you know if there's any way to change the URL to an embed of their most recent video? Or just any of their videos, really.

Comment: No, not by just modifying the URL. I think you'd have to write a script to go into the channel page and get the link to the first video.