# Can't get past youtube consent page again, using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, youtube

So i am accessing the Youtube for a couple of things and they broke about a couple of weeks ago.

I used to be able to do this

```
requests.get(link, cookies={"CONSENT": "YES+42"})
```

So this happens with every youtube link i try, be it a video page, channel page or the main page.

I tried different values for consent and i also tried to pass the cookies in the header, but that didn't change anything. Also tried setting a user agent.

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74127649). What is your initial goal in retrieving the YouTube webpage? Maybe not having the consent pop-up isn't a problem.

Comment: Omg that works. I need to scrape the page for the channel ID and i am using the youtube data API after that, it's just that since they changed this i have been trying to find a fix for it but wasn't able to. I need to improve my searching skills.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Concerning channel ids, as it's a bit messy, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843807) may interest you.

Comment: So on any youtube channels page, if you go to about and share, you have a copy channel id option. I will do that in the future, I just needed a quick fix until then